# How to implement jQuery autocomplete in SlickGrid cell editor

Tags: slickgrid

I am setting up SlickGrid and need to have a column with an autoComplete editor.
I tried it my modifying TextEditor or DateEditor. Nothing works.

Can anybody give me a rough sketch of an implementation by using the TextEditor as a basis?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did this in slick.editors.js - might have some bugs, but should work and help you get started:

```
$.extend(true, window, {
    "Slick": {
      "Editors": {
        "Auto": AutoCompleteEditor,
        "Text": TextEditor,
        "Integer": IntegerEditor,
        "Date": DateEditor,
        "YesNoSelect": YesNoSelectEditor,
        "Checkbox": CheckboxEditor,
        "PercentComplete": PercentCompleteEditor,
        "LongText": LongTextEditor
      }
    }
  });

  var availableTags = [
                        "ActionScript",
                        "AppleScript",
                        "Asp",
                        "BASIC",
                        "C",
                        "C++",
                        "Clojure",
                        "COBOL",
                        "ColdFusion",
                        "Erlang",
                        "Fortran",
                        "Groovy",
                        "Haskell",
                        "Java",
                        "JavaScript",
                        "Lisp",
                        "Perl",
                        "PHP",
                        "Python",
                        "Ruby",
                        "Scala",
                        "Scheme"
                      ];

   function AutoCompleteEditor(args) {
     var $input;
     var defaultValue;
     var scope = this;
     var calendarOpen = false;

     this.init = function () {
       $input = $("<INPUT id='tags' class='editor-text' />");
       $input.appendTo(args.container);
       $input.focus().select();
       $input.autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });
     };

     this.destroy = function () {
       $input.autocomplete("destroy");
     };

     this.focus = function () {
       $input.focus();
     };

     this.loadValue = function (item) {
       defaultValue = item[args.column.field];
       $input.val(defaultValue);
       $input[0].defaultValue = defaultValue;
       $input.select();
     };

     this.serializeValue = function () {
       return $input.val();
     };

     this.applyValue = function (item, state) {
       item[args.column.field] = state;
     };

     this.isValueChanged = function () {
       return (!($input.val() == "" && defaultValue == null)) && ($input.val() != defaultValue);
     };

     this.validate = function () {
       return {
         valid: true,
         msg: null
       };
     };

     this.init();
   }
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi ganeshk, That was exactly what I wanted... thanks... however...

it allways reports in firebug console "$input.autocomplete is not a function". Whatever I did, it does not find autocomplete.
As I read, autocompare is part of jquery-ui-1.8. Right?

Any hint what I could do?

Comment: Glad to be of help - and welcome to SO! Just include `jquery-ui.js` and `jquery-ui.css` in your HTML. You can download both from http://www.jqueryui.com

Comment: I hope this answered your question. Would you mind accepting this as your answer then?

Comment: NP. You'll need to mark this as an answer. Check the FAQ if you need help on how to do this - http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 5):

**Just a little addition to the previous answer.** To make arrow keys work you may want to do `stopPropagation`. Here is an snippet from the editor's `init` method. It is in CoffeeScript but you will get the idea:

```
$input.bind "keydown.nav", (e) ->
    e.stopPropagation() if (e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.DOWN || e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.UP || e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER) && $('ul.ui-autocomplete').is(':visible')
    e.stopImmediatePropagation() if e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.LEFT || e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.RIGHT
```

Regular JQuery translation of the above snippet:

```js
$input.bind("keydown.nav", function(e) {
    if ((e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.DOWN || e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.UP ||
         e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER)
      && $('ul.ui-autocomplete').is(':visible')) e.stopPropagation();

    if (e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.LEFT || e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.RIGHT)
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness and in relation to ganeshk and arkadiy answers:

A user called Extazystas included ganeshk solution on github:

https://gist.github.com/Extazystas/b64d98f072344ec395fa

For autocomplete to work, you need to include arkadiy snippet in the init function as shown below:

```
  $input.focus().select();

// insert from here ------------------------------
$input.bind("keydown.nav", function(e) {
    if ((e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.DOWN || e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.UP ||
         e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.ENTER)
      && $('ul.ui-autocomplete').is(':visible')) e.stopPropagation();

    if (e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.LEFT || e.keyCode == $.ui.keyCode.RIGHT)
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
// insert to here ------------------------------

  $input.autocomplete({
    source: availableOptions
  });
```